# PayPal Button Integration The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: .net, ssl, paypal, blazor, blazor-server-side

We implemented the PayPal Button Integration (https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) on our website and it has been working for the most part. The website is a .Net 6 Blazor Server-Side hosted in Azure App Service with a small audience that sometimes can make payments. For some reason, once in a while, the api endpoint for /v1/oauth2/token throws the following error:

> Message: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner
> exception. Source: System.Net.Http
> Exception.ToString():System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL
> connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
> ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090304): The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted

That causes a domino effect of different calls not working. Any ideas on what could be causing something like this? .Net 6 should use TLS 1.2 by default and Azure App Service should have all cyphers and security setup, plus it's working most of the time.

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, ($"{paypalBaseUrl}/v1/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials"));
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {authToken}");
// Use Http Factory to create Http Client
HttpClient client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: I have been receiving the same intermittent error, starting 15 December 2023. PayPal support are denying this is an issue on their side.

Comment: Yeah, they told me the same thing 

Comment: Log everything about the problem when it occurs and ask Azure's support

Comment: Yes I am getting the same error intermittenly. I have numerous API calls in my server but only the PayPal ones are getting failed with the same error.

Comment: We ended up creating a retry logic where we wait 100 ms per retry and it usually works after the first failure. Not sure what started causing the issue but a retry prevents any customer disruption.